# Moving all files from MANY folders up one level - command line

Tags: command-line, dos, wildcard

I have tens of thousands of `*.wav` files spread out across hundreds of folders. I need help to get command line to move all files up one level. The directory structure for all these files are identical, but the names of the folders vary slightly:

> Z:\Audio\Level*\story*\VOCAB\*.wav

All files are located in the `VOCAB` folders, and I need to move them to the `story*` folders:

> Z:\Audio\Level*\story*\*.wav

I can do this from command line by running a move command on each individual folder, but is there a way to run it recursively on all files within the entire directory?  Can I use a wildcard in the location path?

Notes: 
The * in Level* and story* are numbers 01-24.
I'm on Windows XP Professional.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a similar question in another forum (http://www.computerhope.com/forum/index.php/topic,98046.0/all.html).

Modifying some of their code, here's a batch file script that might do the trick (please try on a small subset before unleashing it on everything):

```
@echo off
set thisdir=%cd%
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /b /ad') do (
    cd /d "%%~dpnA"
    for /f "delims=" %%B in ('dir /b /ad') do (
        echo Level 2 Directory: %%~dpnB
        cd /d "%%~dpnB"
        for /f "delims=" %%C in ('dir /b /ad') do (
            echo Level 3 Directory: %%~dpnC
            cd /d "%%~dpnC"
            move *.* ..\
            cd ..
            rd "%%~dpnC"
        )
        cd ..
    )
    cd..
)
cd /d "%thisdir%
```

Comment: Thanks!! I struggled with this code a bit, before looking back at the forum you referenced. I took a very small bit of the code from that to make a very small and simple batch file with the following code: `@echo off for /f %%P in ('dir /b /od') do copy %%P\VOCAB\*.* .\%%P\ REM for /f %%P in (dir /b /od') do rmdir /s /q %%P\VOCAB` and ran it in each of my `Level*` folders. There are only 24 of those folders, so it was a pretty simple job, and it did the trick! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

try something like:

```
for /r %F in (*.wav) do move %F %~pF\..
```

refer to `for /?` from command prompt as reference (particularly in case I didn't 'code' that quite right...)

I suggest starting it from within `\Audio` directory.

Comment: I'm in favor of a solution like this because of how simple it is!  However, running this command puts all of the files in the starting directory, instead of just moving them up a level.  Any idea how I can use the `%~pF` code to get the files up one level?  Or is that what the `\..` is supposed to do?  (Sorry, I'm unfamiliar with `\..`)

Comment: Yes '..' in a directory, represents the directory just above the one it is located in.